# XMPP network traffic analysis

Tags: xmpp

I am capturing network packets of Gtalk using Microsoft Network Monitor. Very often I see small sessions of communication where a packet with TCP payload of 37 is sent by me to dst port 5222 and I receive an ACK for it. I can't see the contents of this packet because it is encrypted using TLS. Gtalk uses XMPP protocol. Any experts know what does this small session represent? Is it part of protocol specifications? Is there any way I can see the contents of this packet?

Comment: @WhoeverVotedToCloseThisQuestion: Please also tell where in the Stack Universe can I ask this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this being sent periodically, like every 30s, 1m, etc?  If so, it's likely one space character, after it's been (potentially compressed then) encrypted.  Many XMPP endpoints will do this to keep the socket open in the face of the large number of odd middleboxes that assume that if you haven't sent data in a while, the socket is dead.

Comment: Yes this is periodic. I see it every 1 min. Is there any way I can confirm that the client is indeed sending a space character?

Comment: Why doesn't the client just send TCP keep alives?

Comment: @Bruce it doesn't matter if it's literally a space, although that's traditional.  It just has to be a character that the XML parser will essentially ignore between stanzas.

Comment: @Bruce: TCP keep-alives tend to have MUCH longer time horizons, and don't tend to be all that useful with all of the aggressive middleboxes that we find in practice, some of which will lose socket state without sending either a RST or a FIN in either direction if you haven't used the socket recently enough. As well, the TCP keep-alive timer lengths are often system-wide and require admin privs to set.